# Можно ли в django привязать модель к таблице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Например в yii2 можно создать метод

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return "data.ip";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import models

class Table(models.Model):
    field = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_table' # my_table - имя таблицы для связи с моделью
```

Comment: Не понятно почему так?

Comment: @Andru в смысле?

Comment: Да уже нашёл в документации